# I need an Excel formula which will search an array for a specified value and add sum an adjacent cell if found and numerical

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an array A:C with columns 'client numbers, staff, and hours.' Looks like this:

I can't get the array to show correctly so I'm posting an image

[image]

Staff at the bottom are available for shifts, but do not currently have hours assigned.

I would like to create another column with total hours worked for each staff. Thus, I need to search the array for each staff's name, and if the staff's name is found, the adjacent cell is pinged to determine if hours are worked. This number is then summed across all the times a staff name is found.

Can someone help with that? :)

Comment: You may want to take a little time to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: So you are describing SumIf/SumIfs, or am I missing something here?